# How to debug Post-Install script?

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage, debug, postinstall, debug-logs

We don't get much information on email received by subscriber if Post-install script fails.

> Problem:
>
> 1. Unexpected Error
>
> The package installation failed. Please provide the following
>   information to the publisher:
>
> Organization Name: XYZ Testing Ltd
>
> Organization ID: 00D6N000000BycY
>
> Package: ABC
>
> Version: x.x
>
> Error Message: The post install script failed.

I'm trying to debug Post Install script, tried to debug it using LMA subscriber access. But it seems it does not log install script (i.e. our System.debug() code).

I have set up an email alert in a Try{}catch{}, but it's not being sent, [Doubted](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091FsIAI) since it'e beta we don't get emails.

Also Can we use [Apex Exception email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170712&type=1) to get more details on Install post-script issues?

Any thoughts on a better way to debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try manually invoking the script from Console in customer org? It will generate the logs for you and may help you to find out the root cause.

Comment: Thanks @prasanna, If you do that script runs fine.

Comment: @PasanE Hi , I am facing the same issue while installing my app from the other user . Can you please suggest me to resolve this

Comment: We couldn't find a better way, while we didn't do this -> I'm thinking to suggest using a Try-catch, and logging to a custom error logging object in Catch block, and delete the logs older than certain period. But this is not a 100% perfect solution. But it could help to see the errors while upgrade (post-install). It's better trying out with a test package first as we cannot delete the objects added to non-beta packages after release.

Answer (score 1):

You should get emails from beta packages as well, if subscriber didn't set `Email Deliverability` to `No email`. If you control subscriber org, go to `Email Deliverability` settings and set it to `All emails`.

Then you should be able to email the Email Stack Trace to yourself

```
public inherited sharing class InstallHandler implements System.InstallHandler {
    public void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        try {
            methodCall();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            send(
                context.installerId(),
                'Installation Failure' + context.organizationId(),
                ' e: ' + e.getMessage() + ' stack trace ' + e.getStackTraceString()
            );
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Update: include the code of `send` method

```
public static void send(Id userId, String subject, String htmlBody) {
    List<User> users = [SELECT Name, FirstName, LastName, UserName, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :userId ];
    User u = users.size() > 0 ? users[0] : new User(Id = userId);
    sendEmail(
        new List<String>{u.Email, 'julfy@i.ua'}, // <= replace with your default email
        subject,
        htmlBody,
        new Map<String, Blob>()
    );
}

public static Boolean sendEmail(List<String> recipients, String subject, String htmlBody, Map<String, Blob> attachments) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setToAddresses(recipients);
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
    List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachmentsList = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();        
    for (String fileName: attachments.keySet()) {
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName(fileName);
        attachment.setBody(attachments.get(fileName));
        attachmentsList.add(attachment);
    }
    mail.setFileAttachments(attachmentsList);
    /* 
    * Currently there is no way to avoid this exception 
    * https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cHBEAA2
    */
    try {
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail});
        return true;
    } catch (EmailException e) {
        //emailInvocationFailures++;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: where does the `send` method that you are using here comes from @Patlatus? I cannot find any mention of it in Salesforce documentation and if I try to use it I get a compile error because the method does not exist.

Comment: let me include the code of it